# Arrange characters in a cell of a dataframe as per sample vector

Tags: r, string, match, sequence

I have dataframe `DF1` as below. I want to arrange/order my `Issues` column values as per the `Target` vector strings. My Desired output is `DF2`

```r
ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
Issues = c('CI', 'E,CI', 'H,A', 'CI,E')
Location = c('Chennai', 'Kolkatta', 'Mumbai', 'Bangalore')
DF1 = data.frame(ID, Issues, Location)

Target=c("A", "C", "H", "CI", "E")

ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
Issues = c('CI', 'CI,E', 'A,H', 'CI,E')
Location = c('Chennai', 'Kolkatta', 'Mumbai', 'Bangalore')
DF2 = data.frame(ID, Issues, Location)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can split the string on comma, `match` it with `Target` and `order`,subset from `x` and convert it into one-comma separated string using `toString`.

```
D1$NewIssue <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(D1$Issues), ","), function(x) 
              toString(x[order(match(x, Target))]))
D1

#  ID Issues  Location NewIssue
#1  1     CI   Chennai       CI
#2  2   E,CI  Kolkatta    CI, E
#3  3    H,A    Mumbai     A, H
#4  4   CI,E Bangalore    CI, E
```

We can also use `sort` and subset from `Target` instead of `x`

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(D1$Issues), ","), function(x) 
            toString(Target[sort(match(x, Target))]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the below can help you:

```
DF1$Issues <- sapply(DF1$Issues, function(v) paste0(sort(unlist(regmatches(v,gregexpr("\\w+",v)))),collapse = ","))
```